# Upgrading JRE in Mavericks 10.9

Tags: java, macos, osx-mavericks

Am trying to run eclipse in maverick but a dialog box says that version 1.7.0 or later is needed to run Google plugin for Eclipse. My mac has version 1.6.0 when I run java -version from the command line.

I downloaded the latest Java https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp , installed it but still the JRE is 1.6.0. What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the vm in eclipse.ini file in eclipse package contents to the one you just installed.

Please see [Mac OS X - Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value%3a_Mac_OS_X_Example)